# Aptana: Git merge without fast forward

Tags: git, merge, aptana, fast-forward

how can i disable fast-forward for mergining branches in aptana 3 ?

example:

1. create/checkout a branch (foo)
2. commit changes
3. checkout master-branch
4. merge with foo

Answer (score 5):

Set it in project repository configuration

```
git config --add merge.ff false
```

Comment: Note that this might require a recent (1.7.6+) version of git.

Comment: Thanks for the note, i forgot about this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the nearest you get is to use `merge --no-ff`.

Comment: and how can i use --no-ff in the aptana plugin ?