# Aptana, SourceTree and Git - Beginner

Tags: git, aptana, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am just now starting to use version control and my head is spinning! I am trying to wrap my head around branches, checkout, merging and rebasing. I'm sure these are stupid questions but would really appreciate some help.

My projects are PHP. I am using Aptana studio for my IDE, Bitbucket and SourceTree for Git GUI.

So I think I might have a rough idea on how this is supposed to work now. Please tell me where I am wrong.

Say I want to add a new feature. I have a master branch. In Aptana I can right click a file → **Go to team**, and then create a new branch. I can name that branch `feature a1bc`. I make my changes.

Once I am done with this feature and all the changes I click **Team** → **Commit**, then **Team** → **Merge branch** → **master**. This merges my changes back into the master repo.

Is this roughly how I would go about doing feature adds, etc.? Also what do I do if I have 100+ features as time goes on? Do I keep all those feature branches or delete them after they are merged back in?

Comment: There's pretty much an infinite ways on how to do this. If I had any say in things, I'd follow [the git-flow model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). Mostly because it's documented, and comes with [high-level tooling](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to decide if you merge back in `master` as a **fast-forward merge or not**:

[image: git merges]

Since branches are made to **isolate a work** (see "[When should you branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2107672/6309)"), you can regularly incorporate your `feature` branch into `master`, *while* continuing the development of said feature on the `feature` branch.
In that scenario, a **`merge --no-ff`** is advisable (and, [considering Aptana defaults, might better be done in command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9159895/6309)).

However, if you made a branch to isolate a short-live development, you can incorporate back your `feature` branch in `master` through a fast-forward merge (in order to "blend" completely the two branches).
If `master` had some commits while you were developing `feature`, you will need to rebase `feature` on top of `master` first, then merge `feature` in `master` (this will be fast-forward).

For more, see:

- "[Why does git use fast-forward merging by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850369/why-does-git-use-fast-forward-merging-by-default/2850413#2850413)"
- "[git rebase vs git merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/git-rebase-vs-git-merge/804178#804178)"

Comment: VonC,

So after I merge those feature branches back into the development branch do I delete the feature branch? If not I end up with a HUGE list of feature branches. Or is there a way to hide them from the list so they are not showing anymore?

Comment: @ipengineer: for shrot-lived `feature` branch, you clean their history (squashing a few commits, reordering them), then rebase said `feature` branch on top of `master`, and finally merging it fast-forward, making the (cleaned) history of that `feature` branch part of the one of `master`. So in that case, you don't really delete it (in that you keep the commits), you just, by deleting the `feature` branch, deleting the pointer to said branch.

Comment: @ipengineer However, for long-lived `feature` branch, where you merge significant commits back to `master`, then yes, you can delete also `feature` branch, which deletes the pointer but also "forget" all the intermediate commits.

Comment: One of the clearest explanation of a source control best practice I've seen, good work!